Python shiny express dynamic filter options
I have a dataframe of the following format:

I want two dropdown menus where I can filter the dataframe for column 1 and column 2. I want the options for the dropdown to be dynamic in that they reflect the option selected in the other dropdown menu.
E.g. if I have selected Column1 = "A" then only "1" should show up in the dropdown for Column2.
from shiny import reactive
from shiny.express import input, render, ui
import pandas as pd

from data import master_df

@reactive.calc
def filter_data():    
    
    filtered_df = master_df.copy()
    
    if(input.Column1() is not None):
        filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_df['Column1'] == input.Column1()]
    
    if(input.Column2() is not None):
        filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_df['Column2'] == input.Column2()]
    
    return filtered_df

ui.input_selectize("Column1", "Select Column1", filter_data()['Column1'].tolist())

ui.input_selectize("Column2", "Select Column2", filter_data()['Column2'].tolist())


@render.data_frame
def render_data():
    return filter_data()

I have tried the above but I'm getting a "No current reactive context" error.

Please provide a minimal, reproducible example (data is not accessible for us).

Also, regarding the " I want the options for the dropdown to be dynamic in that they reflect the option selected in the other dropdown menu.": Consider that the first dropdown shows "A" and the second dropdown updates to "1". How do you want to return back to the initial state? With this requirement, you could not update dropdown 1 and also not dropdown 2 because the options are limited by the other one.
